# I upgraded Knockout.js, now my templates are broken

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I upgraded knockout.js from 1.2 to 2.1 in my project.  I'm using some basic templates and they seem to be broken.  I am including jQuery.tmpl.js and knockout-2.1.0.js.  Hoping for a quick answer.

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'addressesTemplate', foreach:addresses}"></ul>

<button data-bind="click: addAddress">Add Address</button>

<button data-bind="click: save">Save Account</button>

<script id="addressesTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>
    Address Type: <input data-bind="value: addressType"/><br/>
    Address Line 1: <input data-bind="value: addressLine1"/><br/>
    Address Line 2: <input data-bind="value: addressLine2"/><br/>
    City: <input data-bind="value: city"/><br/>
    State: <input data-bind="value: state"/><br/>
    Country: <input data-bind="value: country"/><br/>
    Zip Code: <input data-bind="value: zipCode"/><br/>
    <button data-bind="click: remove">Remove</button>
    </li>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">



   function addressModel(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            addressType: ko.observable(),
            addressLine1: ko.observable(),
            addressLine2: ko.observable(),
            city: ko.observableArray(),
            state: ko.observableArray(),
            country: ko.observableArray(),
            zipCode: ko.observableArray(),

            remove: function () {
                viewModel.addresses.remove(this);
            }

        };
    }

    var viewModel = {
        id : 0,
        username: ko.observable(""),
        addresses: ko.observableArray([]),
        addAddress: function () {
            this.addresses.push(new addressModel(""));
        },


        save: function () {
            alert(ko.toJSON(this));
            $.ajax({
                url: "/account/Save",
                type: "post",
                data: ko.toJSON(this),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(result) {alert(result.message) },
                failure: function(result) { alert('fail') }
            });
        }

    };


    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me:http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/R3eDR/. As a note, your addressModel having the remove function that points to its parent (and hard-coded at that) is bad. The remove function should be on the viewmodel. If you need more of an explanation of why or how, let me know.

Comment: Try taking out jQuery.tmpl.js, it isn't used anymore.

Comment: If you are not using features of jQuery templates (your example does not), then you can remove it as @Tyrsius mentioned.  The problem is likely that your version of jQuery Templates is too old.  You should see a message indicating that in the console.  Here is a link to a version that does work: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/jquery.tmpl.js.  Removing the dependency is the best choice though.

Comment: removing jQuery.tmpl.js did it.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since removing jquery.tmpl did it, I am adding this as an answer. But for added value, here is your viewModel with the remove function moved up into the viewmodel (and in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/R3eDR/2/))

```
function addressModel(id) {
    return {
        id: id,
        addressType: ko.observable(),
        addressLine1: ko.observable(),
        addressLine2: ko.observable(),
        city: ko.observableArray(),
        state: ko.observableArray(),
        country: ko.observableArray(),
        zipCode: ko.observableArray()
    };
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.id = 0;
    self.username=  ko.observable("");
    self.addresses= ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addAddress= function() {
        self.addresses.push(new addressModel(""));
    };
    self.removeAddress = function(address) {
        self.addresses.remove(address);
    };
};
```

and the new `button` binding:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.removeAddress">Remove</button>
```